# Can multiple fields be grouped on one line of a form?

Tags: forms, tablet, fields

I am designing a form for a tablet. Typically forms are filled out vertically, but in landscape some fields could be represented on one line to save scrolling. For example: height and weight, or first and last name.

My questions are:

- Would too many groupings be confusing to users (e.g. gender and birthdate)?
- How should the multi-field design respond to both portrait and landscape layouts?

Comment: please post a mock for context.

Comment: fields are Name, Email, Gender and Date of birth

Answer (score 1):

Putting input fields next to each other makes them hard to scan for users.
Since users like to scan instead of reading putting them below each other makes it far better in terms of usability.

There are many articles and studies regarding that, for example you could read: https://uxplanet.org/designing-more-efficient-forms-structure-inputs-labels-and-actions-e3a47007114f

Its a pretty decent summary of do's and dont's.

Comment: but I have a problem that the space is small and I want to avoid the scrolling on 7 inch tablet

Comment: Why? Its a myth that users dont like to scroll anyway... there is absolutely no problem to scroll on a mobile device, its a natural and well adapted these days.

Comment: As stated in the link provided, which I agree on. In those cases try to combine the fields into one field. Grouping is just trying to fix a symptom.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main scenario where multiple fields on the same line would be where there is a very strong relationship between them. Eg blood pressure.

Blood pressure is measured as 2 values that go together Systolic/Diastolic, and both values are small numbers eg 120/80. I could see this being displayed on a single line grouped together... but only because they are so tightly related and it would be odd to split them apart.